# Changing Background based on update of TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple android app using JAVA(Android Studio). What I am willing to implement is the background color of the app to change based on the content of the TextView (which is updated constantly between two values "Open" and "Closed"). I have seen that onChanged() must be used but I don`t really understand how to Implement the listener for the TextView.

I tried wrote this :
 `measurementValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox_main); measurementValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {}`
based on what I have found online, but can`t really figure out what the next step is. I am a total newbie so please be kind.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for text change on those 3 callbacks. It depends on your use case.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence textInput, int start, int before, int count) {
    String strInput = textInput.toString();

    if ("open".equalsIgnoreCase(strInput)) {
        // text is "open"
        // change background to desired color
    } else if ("closed".equalsIgnoreCase(strInput)) {
       // text is "closed"
       // change background to desired color
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it would be better if the code could be placed in `afterTextChanged`

Comment: You're most likely right! Same logic can be applied with `Editable` class just by calling `toString()`. But then again OP might have his/her own reason depending on the use case.

Comment: yes. But, this sometimes does not work as expected in some cases. Like getting the length of the string. That is related to this, but that could have been better. Up to you really

Comment: The thing is that the data from the TextView come from a peripheral device. So the TextView is basically what the device is sending through the UART. It seems to me that OnTextChanged works only for EditText? 
I am now receiving this error:
`error: <anonymous com.aceso.blessedtoothbrush.MainActivity$4> is not abstract and does not override abstract method afterTextChanged(Editable) in TextWatcher
        measurementValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {`

Comment: When I add @Override above `measurementValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {}` it says: `error: <identifier> expected
        measurementValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {`. Any ideas?